# Split DateTime into 1-Minute Slots Across the Day

Tags: sql-server

I have a bunch of DateTimes using slqserver express 2012, and I would like to split and allocate those datetimes into 1-minute slots across the day, noting that there will potentially be more than one day in the data. However, I will first concentrate on only one day of data. For example, if I have the following input data:

```
OnTime            OffTime           Duration
2017-11-01 00:03  2017-11-01 00:04  1
2017-11-01 00:08  2017-11-01 00:11  3
2017-11-01 00:13  2017-11-01 00:14  1
2017-11-01 00:21  2017-11-01 00:24  3
2017-11-01 00:26  2017-11-01 00:30  4
```

I would like the output to be slotted into each minute slot of the day, where there are 1440 minutes in the day, and if the datetime spans the minute slot in question and logical 1 is put into the corresponding columns and a 0 otherwise, startin at 0000 = minute slot 0 and 2359 = minute slot 1439. Output data would thus be something like:

```
Minute   Active
0        0
1        0      
2        0
3        1
4        0
5        0
6        0
7        0
8        1
9        1
10       1
11       0
12       0
13       1
14       0
15       0
...      ...
1440     0
```

I was thinking that I could cross apply the datetimes with a duration of one minute but I don't know exactly where to go with that or if its even the best way. I would also be interested in extending this idea to slot into seconds or hours gaps instead of minutes etc. Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards, M

Comment: Do you *have* to do this in SQL?

Comment: I don't have any other tool available to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will generate the resultset you need for some date. You can put it in a function. `cte` part is just for demo purpose you must use your table.

```
DECLARE @somedate date = '2017-11-01'

DECLARE @somedateN nvarchar(10) = CAST(@somedate as nvarchar(10))
DECLARE @start datetime = CAST(@somedateN +' 00:00:00' as datetime),
        @end datetime = CAST(@somedateN +' 23:59:59' as datetime)

-- Simulation of your table with some new rows
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  OnTime,
            OffTime,
            Duration
    FROM (VALUES
    ('2017-11-01 00:03', '2017-11-01 00:04', 1),
    ('2017-11-01 00:08', '2017-11-01 00:11', 3),
    ('2017-11-01 00:13', '2017-11-01 00:14', 1),
    ('2017-11-01 00:21', '2017-11-01 00:24', 3),
    ('2017-11-01 00:26', '2017-11-01 00:30', 4),
    ('2017-11-01 00:59', '2017-11-01 01:30', 31),   -- new row
    ('2017-11-01 23:57', '2017-11-02 00:02', 5)     -- new row
    ) as t(OnTime,OffTime,Duration)
), minutes_ AS ( -- table with all minutes from 0 to 1440
    SELECT  0 as [Minute]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  [Minute] + 1
    FROM minutes_
    WHERE [Minute] <= DATEDIFF(minute,@start,@end) 
)
-- here we go!
SELECT  [Minute],
        CASE WHEN c.Duration IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as [Active]
FROM minutes_ m
LEFT JOIN cte c
    ON m.[Minute] >= DATEDIFF(minute,@start,OnTime) 
    AND m.[Minute] < DATEDIFF(minute,@start,OffTime) 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output:

```
Minute      Active
----------- -----------
0           0
1           0
2           0
3           1
4           0
5           0
6           0
7           0
8           1
9           1
10          1
11          0
12          0
13          1
...
1434        0
1435        0
1436        0
1437        1
1438        1
1439        1
1440        1
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed, you've all really helped me out but I select the solution from gofr1 because it was the easiest for me to understand.

Comment: Is it possible to extend this idea so that there could be an extra column added which would be used for badge. My raw data includes a column for  badge number and I would like to somehow loop through the datetime data for all badges automatically and create a table that I could pull into excel, filter and graph.

Comment: @beliskna yes, you can. But ut is a different question :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll raise it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllMinutesBetweenRange]
(
   @FromDate DATETIME
   ,@ToDate DATETIME

)
RETURNS @Dates TABLE
(
   DateVal DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT @FromDate AS FromDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MI,1,FromDate)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE FromDate < @ToDate
)

INSERT INTO @Dates
SELECT FromDate FROM CTE
option (maxrecursion 0)

RETURN;

END

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATEVAL) AS MINUTE
      ,DATEVAL
      ,CASE WHEN TableA.OnTime IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
FROM [dbo].[GetAllMinutesBetweenRange]('2017-11-01 00:00:00','2017-11-01 23:59:00') Res1
LEFT JOIN TableA ON Res1.DateVal >= TableA.OnTime AND Res1.DateVal< TableA.OffTime
```

The table valued function can be modified to handle the seconds as well

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for you to consider. This query is focused on one day:

```
declare @dateTable table(OnTime datetime, OffTime datetime, Duration int)
insert into @dateTable values('2017-11-01 00:03','2017-11-01 00:04',1)
insert into @dateTable values('2017-11-01 00:08','2017-11-01 00:11',3)
insert into @dateTable values('2017-11-01 00:13','2017-11-01 00:14',1)
insert into @dateTable values('2017-11-01 00:21','2017-11-01 00:24',3)
insert into @dateTable values('2017-11-01 00:26','2017-11-01 00:30',4)

declare @result table(minute int, active bit)
declare @length int = 1440
declare @index int = 0

while @index <= @length
begin
    insert into @result values(@index,0)
    set @index = @index + 1
end

update t
set t.active = case when d.OnTime is not null then 1 else 0 end 
from @result as t
left join @dateTable as d on t.minute >= datepart(hour,ontime)*60 + datepart(minute,ontime)
                        and t.minute < datepart(hour,offtime)*60 + datepart(minute,offtime)

select * from @result
```

Answer (score -1):

try This

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT
    SeqNo = 0,    
    Strt = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    SeqNo = SeqNo+1,  
    Strt = DATEADD(minute,1,Strt)
  FROM CTE
    WHERE CAST(CAST(Strt AS DATE) AS DATETIME)=CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)

)
SELECT
  SeqNo AS Minute,
  Active = CASE WHEN T1.Duration IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM CTE C1
  LEFT JOIN T1
    ON CAST(T1.OnTime AS DATETIME) >= CAST(C1.Strt AS DATETIME)
      AND CAST(T1.OffTime AS DATETIME) <= CAST(C1.Strt AS DATETIME)
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: "Invalid object name 'T1'."

Comment: @blobbles, You are supposed to make the edits based on your scenario, T1 should be replaced with your table name.

Comment: It's not clear in your code that this is what you are supposed to do. Edit your answer to indicate this, preferably create your own table first to show people. Note answers above are runnable as is and/or tell you where to replace what. All you have is "try This", which does not say to replace table names, or which tables you need to replace.